# Reading Spss Data file in R

Tags: r, expss

i am using Expss pakage .
`df<-read_spss("test.SAV")`
I shows the following:

> Warning message: In foreign::read.spss(enc2native(file),
>   use.value.labels = FALSE,  :   Tally.SAV: Very long string record(s)
>   found (record type 7, subtype 14), each will be imported in
>   consecutive separate variables

It shows 4174 Variables in environment Panel.Actual Number of Variables in the Data file around 400.
Can anyone among you please help me on this.

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/foreign/html/read.spss.html , this will help you to handle this error.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment `foreign::read.spss` split SPSS long (>255 chars) characters variables into the several columns. If the such columns are empty you can drop them without any issues.
Convenience function for this:

```
remove_empty_characters_after_foreign = function(data){
    empty_chars = vapply(data, FUN = function(column) is.character(column) & all(is.na(column)), FUN.VALUE = logical(1))
    additional_chars = grepl("00\\d$", colnames(data), perl = TRUE)
    to_remove = empty_chars & additional_chars
    if(any(to_remove)){
        message(paste0("Removing ", paste(colnames(data)[to_remove], collapse = ", "),"..."))
    }
    data[,!to_remove, drop = FALSE]

}

df = remove_empty_characters_after_foreign(df)
```